# Does it make sense as a long-term investment to sell Put Options of a Bonds ETF?

Tags: put-options, bond-funds

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I'm thinking of selling Put Options of a Bonds ETF. For this to work, there obviously must be a bias for the share price of the ETF to go up long-term.

My understanding is that the share price of a Bonds ETF might go up if:

- The ETF does not distribute 100% of the bonds' interest payments to investors, or
- Interest rates go down, causing the price of the underlying bonds to go up.

Is this all there is to it? If so, do bond ETFs usually distribute 100% of the interest payments to investors? If so, does that mean that the only way this strategy is profitable, is if interest rates go down over the course of the Options Contract, causing the share price of the ETF to go up?

Even if 100% of the interest is distributed to investors, is this fact already baked into the price of the Put Option?

I'm particularly interested in [VCLT](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VCLT?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly9kdWNrZHVja2dvLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAMNYZHz8yCF6Kx2qox3jBTLdOFIouKkPFNaRu6rqi2UlHZGTsAYi3GoO-tRsPeNHZoZIfT-nH-k3pwf-eftLhsiF0Xi2k_dcF7lMYMyCnX6QyYD5y7hz41_6hXlfIiJZ5HUr77gstptg8Ssle0c3-B68pAbiZqg-fHJpWuR-D8NP) for implementing this strategy on.

Answer (score 1):

> does that mean that the only way this strategy is profitable, is if interest rates go down

Interest rates can't fall much further.

> do bond ETFs usually distribute 100% of the interest payments to investors?

The fund managers might keep a tiny fraction of a percent as a management fee, but *the purpose* of bonds is to pay interest, and therefore it's the purpose of bond funds.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The answer might be a bit short but it's not wrong. Historically speaking, US rates are more likely to go up than to go down further.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD The answer is not wrong, but it does not address the question. The question is not about the likely direction of interest rates in the future.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus if put options can only be profitable if interest rates fall, but interest rates can't fall much further, then put options can't be very profitable.

Comment: @RonJohn That is the question. Are put options only profitable if interest rates fall? Other people here have mentioned other factors like credit spreads and dividends being baked into the option's premium. It looks like interest rate movements are not the only factor to consider, and that is what I'm trying to expand on, not whether interest rates at the moment are expected to go up or down.

Comment: @RonJohn - **If put options can only be profitable if interest rates fall, but interest rates can't fall much further, then put options can't be very profitable.**  That isn't true.  One can make a profit with a short put if share price moves up, implied volatility contracts and/or time decay erodes the extrinsic value of the put.

Answer (score 1):

> For this to work, there obviously must be a bias for the share price of the ETF to go up long-term.

It doesn't have to go up - as long as the price doesn't decline below your strike it could trade sideways or even go down some

> Is this all there is to it? If so, do bond ETFs usually distribute 100% of the interest payments to investors?

The bond coupons are passed onto the ETF investors as dividends (monthly for $[VCLT](https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/VCLT/Dividends/))

> Interest rates go down, causing the price of the underlying bonds to go up.

That's correct but since you mentioned $VCLT (Vanguard Long-Term Corporate Bond ETF) you also need to consider credit spreads, which could widen even if rates don't move. Additionally, the slope of the rates curve could change, so it further depends on the durations of the bonds included in the ETF.

---

It's really not that different from selling puts on other ETFs that pay dividends.

It's important to consider implied volatility (IV) compared to historical volatility (HV). Since bond ETFs have relatively low volatility, option premiums are commensurately low. In order to generate meaningful income, you'd have to sell a lot of contracts or choose a strike that's close to the money, both of which are risky.

I'm not sure I understand your point about selling puts as a long-term investment. Theta increases as the options approach expiry. Ideally, you'd repeatedly sell relatively short-dated options, rather than few long-dated ones.

After looking at the [option chain for VCLT](https://marketchameleon.com/Overview/VCLT/OptionChain/), I also note that there are few expiries to choose from and there's almost no volume/open interest. As a result, bid-ask spreads are quite wide, which makes it hard to unwind the position to take profits/avoid losses before expiry.

Comment: I want to direct some of the margin available in my account towards bonds. I figured that if a sold naked puts deep in the money with expiration dates far in the future, the risk/reward profile would be very similar to just buying the ETF outright but without paying any margin interest to the broker. Right before the option expires, the plan is to buy it back (hopefully at a lower price), rinse and repeat. It's all about saving on margin interest while simulating the risk/reward one would be exposed to from simply buying the ETF directly. Is this idea sound at all?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus that's different question... Deep ITM options have comparatively little time premium. Your Delta exposure would be practically the same as if you bought the ETF outright but you'd miss out on the dividends.

Comment: As noted by 0xFEE1DEAD, Deep ITM options have comparatively little time premium and given VCLT's low IV, even less.  You also have to take into account that  VCLT pays about a 27 cent per month dividend and that will increase the likelihood of early assignment of a deep ITM write.  Unless you have some deep seated belief that VCLT is going to rise sharply, you're just taking on a lot of downside risk for minimal reward.

Comment: @BobBaerker I don't think I care about time premium or early assignment. All I'm trying to do is simulate the risk/reward profile of buying the ETF outright; that is, ride the fund's up and down price movements. I wouldn't have any more downside risk compared to owning the ETF outright, and if the option is deep in-the-money enough, reward should also resemble that of owning the ETF outright (minus dividends). No?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus it seems like your goal/question changes with each comment... if you want to ride the price movements **up** and down, you should buy a call and sell a put for a synthetic forward.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD By "ride down" I meant have a loss similar to what I normally would by owning the ETF outright; not profit from down price movements.

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus yes and that's exactly why you'd want a long call + short put with the same strike/maturity instead of just shorting a put...

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus - Here's an explanation of [synthetic option positions](https://www.optionstrading.org/improving-skills/advanced-terms/synthetic-positions/).  Read the one about Synthetic Long Stock.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD I'm not sure why I would need to buy a call? Is it simply to eliminate the profit ceiling that exists when just selling a put? If so, wouldn't selling the put really, REALLY deep in the money practically (though not in theory) accomplish the same thing by setting that ceiling really high?

Comment: Axiomatic - If you want to ride the fund's up and down price movements then the synthetic long stock position would be a better choice than selling a deep ITM put for several reasons. 1) It has a delta of 100. 2) Since the dividend is baked into option prices, the synthetic will be generate a credit (you're indirectly benefiting from the dividend). 3) OTOH, your short put will be assigned early if too deep ITM and if not as deep ITM, as VCLT rises, the put's delta will decrease and your participation rate will decline. It might be helpful if you indicate which put you are thinking of selling

Answer (score 1):

The primary driver of share price for a bond ETF is interest rates.  They are inversely related.  Since interest rates are so low and can't drop much further, VCLT isn't going to rise a lot because of that.

The secondary driver is investor mentality.  VCLT periodically has a 10% correction as investor/trader perceptions change (for example, see the inverted yield curve fears of late 2018 and the Covid correction last year).

VCLT issues:

- Implied volatility is very low so the payoff for selling options isn't good.
- Open interest is low, resulting in illiquid options with wider bid/ask spreads.  That also makes it more costly to close the position if need be.
- Put premium appears to be fatter than call premiums but this is a function of dividends being priced into the options (a dividend raises put premium and lowers call premium).  VCLT has been going ex-dividend every month for about 27 cents so share price is going to drop that amount every month.  Selling a long dated option anywhere near the money is likely to be assigned. So if it's a December expiration, outside of market forces that move share price, with a short put you're agreeing to but at the strike, knowing that share price $1.62 lower (6 dividends) by expiration.  However, you're only receiving about 1/2 that amount in baked in put premium increase.

Selling puts on VCLT isn't a good income play.

Comment: 1) I'm not trying to profit from implied volatility. I'm just trying to profit from the option's intrinsic value change.

2) I understand bid/ask spreads are comparatively wide for this position. That's a good point against this strategy.

3) If the option gets assigned early, couldn't I just sell the underlying right away and sell a new contract with the same strike price and expiration date, putting me back on track with the remaining baked-in dividend premium increase that I would have otherwise missed?

Comment: @AxiomaticNexus 1) What do you think it means to be short Vega when IV increases? 3) yes but see 2) you might not be able to do so at prices that make sense, or at all

Answer (score 1):

Good answers here, but one thing to keep in mind is that when you sell single options, your profit is limited to the premium that you get upfront. Your best case scenario is that the option is not exercised, and you don't have to pay any more to close your position.

So even if VCLT triples in your investment horizon, your profit will be capped at the premium you received.  If you want to bet on VCLT going up, just buy the ETF and don't mess with options.

Comment: My reasoning is that if the option is deep in-the-money enough, the risk/reward profile is reasonably similar to simply owning the ETF outright. Yes, if the price of the ETF triples by the end of the options contract, I would be losing on profits, but that's an unreasonable prediction to make. In fact, I'm not even expecting the option to go out-of-the-money by the end of the contract, the idea is to simply profit (or lose) from the intrinsic value change of the option.

Comment: My point was just that your upside is limited, while your downside is not. All else being equal, options lose value over time. So your bet is that either the implied volatility or the underlying price goes up (or some combination) sufficiently to overcome the "time decay".

Comment: Yes, theoretically, but if the put option is sold really, REALLY deep in-the-money, practically speaking there is very little chance of hitting that upside limit you're talking about. That's the point I was trying to make. I understand that the risk/reward profile is not exactly the same as buying the ETF outright, but in practice, I believe it is pretty close.